# how to interpret the linux df cmd result

Tags: linux

After a use of `df -h` to get the disk usage, I wasn't able to figure out where that `Use%` value of *24%* came from:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_uer1-lv_root
                      361G   81G  263G  24% /
tmpfs                 2.0G  444K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             194M   23M  162M  13% /boot
```

The capacity is *361 GB* and available space is *263 GB*. So *361-263 = 98 GB* is used (not 81 GB ?), which is about 27.1%. If Used/Size, *81/361 = 22.4%*.

I use `boost` to get the disk usage information. The Capacity and Available sizes are close with the numbers here.

How do you interpret above result numbers?

Comment: The 24% is 81 / (81 + 263)GB.

Answer (score 3):

Root reserves 5% (?) of the available disk space for root usage by default.  This is to prevent situations where root cannot login to fix whatever is wrong.  This is probably the source of the Use% and the Used/Size value that you're seeing.

Comment: Given today's typical disk sizes, that default of 5% (or, in some cases 10%) can be quite a bit, so I'm usually in the habit of specifying 1% or even sometimes 0% for larger file systems... And, usually, it should only really matter on "system" file systems - root, `/usr`, `/var`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

For most Unix filesystems, some fraction of available space is reserved for the superuser.  This amount is configurable when the file system is created.  This free space threshold gives a little margin both for performance reasons and so some non-error situations may be fixed by the superuser moving files around.  Without that space, there is no way to move files.

It looks like your case has about 17GB reserved, which is about 5%, a typical default value.